# Showing navigation drawer created in react-native over a native screen (iOS Android)

Tags: android, swift, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am creating an application in react-native, but not all the screens are in react-native. Some of the screens will be in native Swift and Java code as well.

This app will have a navigation drawer which I am thinking to build using https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation

The question is how do I show this navigation drawer in the screens built natively.

PS I am a newbie to react-native world.